# rspec with factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factories:

```
Factory.define :producer, :class => User do |f|
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "producer_#{n}@shit.com" }
  f.password  "foobar"
  f.password_confirmation "foobar"
  f.role      "producer"
end

Factory.define :business do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "business_#{n}" }
  f.association(:producer, :factory => :producer)
end

Factory.define :deal do |d| 
  d.sequence(:title) { |n| "deal_#{n}" }
  d.sequence(:desc) { |n| "deal_desc_#{n}" }
  d.cap "50" 
  d.rate "2" 
  d.start Date.today - 1     # This is the date where you put in db
  d.end Date.today + 7
  d.association :business
end
```

now when I do the following:

```
  before(:each) do 
    @consumer = test_sign_in(Factory(:consumer))
    @deal = Factory(:deal)
  end
```

I am getting an error:

```
 Failure/Error: @deal = Factory(:deal)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `producer=' for #<Business:0x007fb494290090>
 # ./deals_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>
```

(Line 15 refers to `@deal = Factory(:deal)` )

Does anyone know why? I am very new to factory girl and I can't seem to find the documentation explaining association and sequence very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is obviously linked to the creation of your `producer` association.

Since you're using the old dsl, I'd suggest two solutions:

```
Factory.define :business do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "business_#{n}" }
  #try this:
  f.association(:user, :factory => :producer)
  #or this:
  f.after_build { |biz| biz.user = Factory.build(:producer) }
end
```

The use of `after_build` or `after_create` is really a matter of choice, depending on your tests purposes.

[Here is a link to the new dsl lookup](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/7176629856/factory-girls-new-look).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still getting the same error despite the change. do you know why? (I updated the main question as well)

Comment: mmmm, and did you try the `after_build` method?

Comment: yes I did as well. Do you know what inspired the producer= anywhere in Factory?

Comment: what's the relationship between `business` and `user`? The error is in the chain: Factory(:deal) => triggers Factory(:business) => triggers with error Factory(:producer) because of the relationship (thus my question)

Comment: I pasted this in a gist because it's pretty long. It's 1:1. https://gist.github.com/7899955d8e2f033ed1b2